# munin main page not displaying after install

Tags: linux, monitoring

Using: Centos 6.4

I have installed munin, but I'm having issues accessing main page.

This is how it looks when I access it using my_server_ip/munin

[image]

I have installed munin from EPEL repo, and it installed all required dependencies.

This is /etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf

```
 # This file can be used as a .htaccess file, or a part of your apache
 # config file.
 #
 # For the .htaccess file option to work the munin www directory
 # (/var/www/html/munin) must have "AllowOverride all" or something close
 # to that set.
 #
 # As a config file enclose it in <directory> like so:
 #
 <directory /var/www/html/munin>

 AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd
 AuthName "Munin"
 AuthType Basic
 require valid-user

 # This next part requires mod_expires to be enabled.
 #
 # We could use <IfModule mod_expires> around here, but I want it to be
 # as evident as possible that you either have to load mod_expires _or_
 # you coment out/remove these lines.

 # Set the default expiery time for files 5 minutes 10 seconds from
 # their creation (modification) time.  There are probably new files by
 # that time.

  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault M310

  </directory>
 ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is the munin apache configuration file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/munin.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like it was a permissions issue

```
 drwxr-xr-x 4 munin munin 4096 Apr  5 15:20 munin
```

I had to change ownership to apache

```
     chown apache:apache -R munin
```

and it worked